# Arch Linux c++ standard library header is not valid UTF-8

Tags: locale, unicode

I'm getting a pretty mystifying error when I try and compile programs using both g++ and clang in Arch Linux. The smallest program which produces the error is

```
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't include `locale`, the error goes away. (I originally found this when compiling a program that included `iomanip`, which includes `locale`.)

I saved the error messages to files for [clang](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y34es7xkwq3ij1q/clang_output.txt?dl=0) and [g++](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hrvcxq7i65hl0f/g%2B%2B_output.txt?dl=0); those are several megabytes large so I won't copy them here. There are lots of warnings about "null character ignored", and I get a warning from the program `/usr/bin/locale` that some source file is not valid UTF-8.

My locale is set to `en_US.UTF-8`. This is the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've tried setting `LC_ALL`; reinstalling binutils and coreutils; setting the locale again with localectl; all to no effect.

Comment: Uh, why `<locale>` and not `<locale.h>` ?

Comment: Looks like it's #including the executable file `/usr/bin/locale`. What `-I` options are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: @thrig, He said this was C++, and many C++ headers don't have a `.h` extension. I agree with Mark Plotnick that we need to see the `-I` options as it probable is including a binary and not a header file.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick and @icarus you're both right, it appears to be including `/usr/bin/locale` instead of the header file. I had some environment variables set to look for headers in my `$~/.local/include/` and must have set them wrong.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I suggest you convert this into an answer and we can get this closed.

Comment: @korrok Can you provide more details about the environment variables and gcc options that caused the problem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I had `C_INCLUDE_PATH = $HOME/.local/include/`, as well as a few other environment variables pointing to `~/.local/`, so I can install a few things from source without using super-user privileges.

Comment: Were there any variables or symlinks that included `/usr/bin`?